# Monitor connection for GPU mining

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-setup, xmr-stak-amd

I'm currently mining on 6 x HP Z420 Pc's E5 Xenon CPU about 300h each. I want to move to GPU - one in each unit.

The PC's have Nvidia K2000 cards fitted and used for the monitor. I don't want to use these so I've bought some Asus fx480 Dual and fitted one. Its not working with xmr-stak-amd (windows just reports its stopped working, no other info)

To start with can I ask if it matters where the monitor is plugged in, on board graphics, the K2000 card or the fx480 I actually want to use?

Although I've googled around for instructions I'm finding it hard to get detailed step by step instructions for a noob, anyone recommend a guide somewhere? I'm not sure I've set up the config file to point at the fx480 card?

Many thanks
Les